# Vue js :src="url" c асинхронно полученным url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

передо мной стоит задача, асинхронно получить url картинки и динамически задать его в img, соответсвенно я написал асинхронный метод, который должен возвращать url, который надо связать v-bind'ом с элементом img, но асинхронный метод возвращает промис, как можно это грамотно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
promise.then(url => {this.url = url});
```

url, конечно должен был быть объявлен в data, чтобы он был реактивной переменной.